# Why my multithreaded file download doesn't work properly?

Tags: multithreading, file, delphi, indy, download

When program starts, automatically downloads given EXE file, but if I want to abort the current process and restart to download again or/and if EXE is downloaded successfully one time and would like to download again, program stops with error message: "raised exception class EIdHTTPProtocolException"

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,idhttp, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient,
  ComCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure IdHTTP1WorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
      AWorkCountMax: Integer);
    procedure IdHTTP1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
      AWorkCount: Integer);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure DownloadFile;

  end;

type
  xy = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure friss;

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  szal:xy;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure xy.friss;
begin

ShowMessage('kész');
szal.terminate;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  //abort
begin

szal.Suspend;
szal.Terminate;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);   //restart
begin
szal:=xy.Create(true);
szal.Resume;
end;

procedure tform1.DownloadFile;
var
  Url, FileName: String;
begin

idhttp1:=idhttp1.Create(self);
  Url := 'http://livecd.com/downloads/ActiveDataStudioSetup.exe';
  Filename := 'c:\setup.zip';

  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get(Url, Stream);
    Stream.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
    IdHTTP1.free;
  end;
end;


procedure xy.execute;
begin

form1.DownloadFile;
Synchronize(friss);

end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
szal:=xy.Create(true);
szal.Resume;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCount: Integer);
begin
  form1.ProgressBar1.Position:=AWorkCount;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdHTTP1WorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCountMax: Integer);
begin
 form1.ProgressBar1.Max:=AWorkCountMax;
 form1.ProgressBar1.Position:=0;
end;

end.
```

Source code: http://pastebin.com/9DvSyTD7
Project: http://osztott.com/ubXN/cucc.zip

Comment: What error message? And please add your code to your question.

Comment: Throw all that code away and start again. The worst I can see is that you totally misused a thread and that you're not properly constructing `TIdHTTP` instance.

Comment: You've provided neither error message nor code. The best we can do is say that your program doesn't work because your code is broken.

Comment: #GolezTrol: Project has been added.

Error message is various.

Comment: update: error message: raised exception class EIdHTTPProtocolException

Comment: Does the error come with a message, or do you only know its class? Why are you suspending and resuming threads. That's something you are supposed never to do.

Comment: See [Stopping Delphi Indy threads without having to wait end Timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9537620/576719).

Comment: This code is part of the bigger program. And I wanted to imitate that, if user cannot download exe firstly, he/she could download secondly.

Comment: @LURD, let's just hope no one will implement `Execute` method as it's shown in the anwser you linked (I see it's marked as pseudocode showing just a principle how to interrupt `TIdHTTP` operation, but still).

Comment: @TLama, `FIdHTTP.Disconnect;` is the command to use :)

Comment: @LURD, raising exception in `OnWork` event handler can do that too. However, I would personally prefer to use `Disconnect` as you say. Still, I would suggest to rewrite the OP's code from scratch :)

Comment: I cannot correct it. I gave up :D

Comment: @roll: You can't correct it because the code you showed is all wrong to begin with. I was in the middle of writing a corrected version when this question got closed.

Comment: Could you send me to my email if it is done? That would be awesome.
vipdays@kavmaster.freeserver.me

Comment: Question has enough information to diagnose the problem and should be reopened.

Comment: It is opened, everybody can post comment. Anybody could help me with some code?

Answer (score 1):

`EIdHTTPProtocolException` means the HTTP server sent back an error, such as if the requested resource is not found or cannot be accessed.  That has nothing to do with your threading logic.

However, there are a lot of problems with your code in general - misuse of `TThread` and dynamic components, not syncing the worker thread with the main UI thread, etc.

Try something more like this instead:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure StartDownload;
    procedure StopDownload;
    procedure DownloadFinished(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  IdHTTP, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdSync;

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TDownloadThread = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure HTTPWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Integer);
    procedure HTTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Integer);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    property ReturnValue;
    property Terminated;
  end;

  TDownloadStatusNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected 
    Value: Integer;
    DownloadBegin: Boolean;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AValue: Integer: ADownloadBegin: Boolean); reintroduce;
  end;

  TFreeDownloadThreadNotify = class(TIdNotify)
  protected
    Thread: TDownloadThread;
    procedure DoNotify; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AThread: TDownloadThread); reintroduce;
  end;

procedure TDownloadThread.Execute;
var
  Url, Filename: string;
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Url := 'http://livecd.com/downloads/ActiveDataStudioSetup.exe';
  Filename := 'c:\setup.zip';

  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    HTTP.OnWorkBegin := HTTPWorkBegin;
    HTTP.OnWork := HTTPWork;

    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      HTTP.Get(Url, Stream);
      Stream.SaveToFile(Filename);
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
  ReturnValue := 1;
end;

procedure TDownloadThread.HTTPWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Integer);
begin
  if Terminated then SysUtils.Abort;
  if AWorkMode = wmRead then
    TDownloadStatusNotify.Create(AWorkCountMax, True).Notify;
end;

procedure TDownloadThread.HTTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Integer);
begin
  if Terminated then SysUtils.Abort;
  if AWorkMode = wmRead then
    TDownloadStatusNotify.Create(AWorkCount, False).Notify;
end;

constructor TDownloadStatusNotify.Create(AValue: Integer; ADownloadBegin: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create;
  Value := AValue;
  DownloadBegin := ADownloadBegin;
end;

procedure TDownloadStatusNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  if DownloadBegin then
  begin
    Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
    Form1.ProgressBar1.Max := Value;
  end else
  begin
    if Form1.ProgressBar1.Max > 0 then
    begin
      Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := Value;
    end else
    begin
      // the download size is unknown (most likely chunked) so
      // display the current Value somewhere else...
    end;
  end;
end;

constructor TFreeDownloadThreadNotify.Create(AThread: TDownloadThread);
begin
  inherited Create;
  MainThreadUsesNotify := True;
  Thread := AThread;
end;

procedure TFreeDownloadThreadNotify.DoNotify;
begin
  Thread.Free;
end;

var
  szal: TDownloadThread = nil;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StartDownload;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  //abort
begin
  StopDownload;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);   //restart
begin
  StopDownload;
  StartDownload;
end;

procedure TForm1.StartDownload;
begin
  szal := TDownloadThread.Create(True);
  sza1.OnTerminate := DownloadFinished;
  szal.Resume;
end;

procedure TForm1.StopDownload;
begin
  if sza1 <> nil then
  begin
    szal.Terminate;
    sza1.WaitFor;
    FreeAndNil(sza1);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.DownloadFinished(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if sza1.ReturnValue = 1 then
    ShowMessage('kész')
  else if sza1.Terminated then
    ShowMessage('félbeszakadt')
  else
    ShowMessage('hiba');

  if not sza1.Terminated then
  begin
    TFreeDownloadThreadNotify.Create(sza1).Notify;
    sza1 := nil;
  end;
end;

end.
```