# How to excecute code in parallel with Indy.Post

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe7

I want to send a Post to a server that is slow. The server won't answer for 20 minutes (or more) and the whole application freezes.

I would like to unfreeze the GUI and at the same time, while waiting for the Post response to process the data from previous Post commands.

Here is how I send the Post command:

```
  { POST }
  procedure TJob.SendToServer; 
  begin
  ...  
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(NIL);
  TRY
    TRY
     Server.Rspns:= lHTTP.Post(ApiServer, MegaSeqFileName);        { This won't freeze the GUI anymore because now TJob.SendToServer function is called in a TPostThread thread }                                      
    EXCEPT
     on E: Exception DO                                                                                  { Catch Internet connection problems }
      begin
       Application.ProcessMessages;
       Status:= jsNotSubmited;
       ParentTask.Log.AddError(E.Message);  
       EXIT;                                                                                          
      end;
    END;
  FINALLY
    FreeAndNil(lHTTP);
  END;
```

This is the Thread code:

```
TYPE
  TPostThread= class(TThread)
  public
    Job: TJob;
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure Done;
  end;

procedure TPostThread.Done;
begin
 Job.ThreadDone:= TRUE;
end;

procedure TPostThread.Execute;
begin
 Job.SendToServer;                                           { Send job and collect results }
 Synchronize(Done);
end;
```

and this is how I start the thread

```
   Job.ThreadDone:= FALSE;
   Thread:= TPostThread.Create(TRUE);
   Thread.Job:= Job;                             
   Thread.FreeOnTerminate:= FALSE;              
   Thread.Start;                                 {This calls: Job.SendToServer }

   REPEAT
     DelayEx(2000);
     if Aborted then
      begin
       MesajInfo('Task aborted.');
       Thread.Terminate;
       FreeAndNil(Thread); <----freezes here!
       EXIT(FALSE);
      end;
     //todo: run other tasks here (more exactly get results from previous Posts and send them to a different web server)
   UNTIL Job.ThreadDone;
   FreeAndNil(Thread);
```

The problem is that when I set Aborted = True, the thread won't exit. It freezes on FreeAndNil(Thread)... which is natural, because I don't check the Terminated in Thread.Execute.

Comment: When you free the thread, it waits for the thread procedure to return. Which it does not. Your call to `ProcessMessages` has to go. It's wrong in the main thread, and it's even more wrong in the worker thread. You'll want to step back a little and put some design and abstraction into this. At the moment you seem to have a large glob of code which allows any part to access any other part. No good will come of such an approach.

Comment: Agree with you @DavidHeffernan. But I think the biggest problem is that I don't handle the Terminated signal in TPostThread.Execute. But how can I handle that when the whole Execute procedure is just one line of code?

Comment: You need to be able to abort the `Post`. Can that be done?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-Good question. I think my questions is 'two in one'. Once, my application freezes on shut down (because of the above code) and second (how to run code in parallel with Post).... well, it might be solved once we solve the first one.

Comment: I just found this. I will dig in now to see if it can be of help for my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535792/stopping-delphi-indy-threads-without-having-to-wait-end-timeout

Comment: The key is being able to stop the POST operation. Then you'll need to tidy up the code considerably but you know that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan- :) :) :) Yes. I know that.

Comment: Typically, to abort the `Post()`, you can use the `OnWork...` event to raise an exception when the thread's `Terminated` property is true.  However, those events are only called when bytes are actually being transmitted in either direction. if the server is really taking 20+ minutes to reply (why??), and `TIdHTTP` is just sitting there completely idle, the `OnWork...` events are not going to be called. The only option in that situation is to `Disconnect()` the socket from another thread context.  And even that is not guaranteed to work on all platforms (it does on Windows, though).

Comment: does windows have async HTTP, something like IO completion ports ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau-The 70 cores server (not mine) has to process a 12MB file. This should take under 20 seconds but because there are lots of users sending jobs, the response is quite slow. They had an old version of the server where you just uploaded the file and instantly got back a 'ticket' number. Then you would return every 2-3 minutes with that ticket to check if your job is done. Not they 'improved' the server and you get the results bank, instead of the ticket. So, I need to let the user to abort the current job and/or to exit the program without waiting 20minutes (sometimes 45).

Comment: @RemyLebeau- 1. The program is frozen during Post. Where can I call Disconnect?  2. What happens if I simply kill the thread?

Answer (score 1):

I have this temporary solution, without threads, based on an idea from @RemyLebeau:

```
procedure TJob.OnHTTPProgress(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
 if UserAborted=true then TIdHTTP(ASender).Disconnect;
 Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

I know **THIS IS NOT** the good answer, only a dirty hack (this is why I will never mark this answer as accepted), but it made my program work, and I badly need to make it work in the next 1-2 weeks. It allows me to do both things: stop the program (during upload) and prevent the GUI from freezing.

I can return later to fix this nastyty.

Comment: Why do you call ProcessMessages? It would slow down downloading and it does not make any sense in a thread. That is not a dirty hack, you should call it like this in a separate procedure like "TPostThread.Stop". Just use "raise" in Progress.

Comment: I call ProcessMessages to unfreeze the GUI (as explained). I don't call ProcessMessages in a thread.

Comment: Do you use TPostThread? If yes, OnHTTPProgress is called in a thread and you call ProcessMessages in a thread. If you call it in a main thread, don't use it either. Use TIdAntiFreeze - your GUI will not freeze and you will be able to disconnect it (not ideal solution but will work).